# how to use NewAggregationQuery in firestore with golang

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

I found that `NewAggregationQuery` is a method of firestore Query.

I have a query, something like

```golang
q = fs.Collection("profiles").Where("age", "==", 18)
res, err := q.NewAggregationQuery().WithCount("count").Get(context.Background())

fmt.Printf("res: %v of type %T\n", res, res)
```

I get

```
res: map[count:integer_value:5] of type firestore.AggregationResult
```

and with:

```
fmt.Printf("res: %v of type %T\n", res["count"], res["count"])
```

I get:

```
res: integer_value:5 of type *firestore.Value
```

And with things like

```
res["count"].(*firestore.Value)
```

I get

```
compilation error, undefined: firestore.Value
```

How can I convert that to an int?

Comment: @ZekeLu I do a similar thing, that is import  "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/firestore/v1" to have access to Value and then call GetIntegerValue(), but import that doesn't looks a bit dirty?

Comment: That's a good question. Since it's a part of the public API (see the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/go/docs/reference/cloud.google.com/go/firestore/latest/apiv1)), I think it's ok to import the package. I'm not sure whether a wrapper will be provided to make it easy to retrieve the result, but for now, this seems the only solution. The pull request ["feat(firestore): adds COUNT aggregation query](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/pull/6692/files#diff-73750838aad768db3e6a40472d73c1c18d6e3ba01b27f530e68b57fdf5eed513R1821)  retrieves the value in the same way.

Comment: I just updated the answer to add the reference to the test [TestIntegration_CountAggregationQuery](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/6de8edada13c751ded733e924174e5b46277fcc6/firestore/integration_test.go#L2023-L2033), which retrieves the value in the same way.

Comment: @ZekeLu Looks like it is in an early stage,  your package looks more official than mine.